# Reverse SCP over SSH connection

Tags: ssh, scp

I pretty often need some file from some server when I'm on my laptop.  But if I don't know where that file is, I have to `ssh` into the server, look around, `exit`, and then `scp server:file .`.  If I'm working with my desktop and my server, both of which have static IPs, I can just SCP the file in reverse (`scp desktop:~ file`), but I can't do that for my laptop.  Is there any nice way to SCP a file backwards over an SSH connection?  So that the computer I connect to with SSH sends a file backwards to the client?

Comment: Why not use mDNS?

Comment: I believe that this question has already been correctly answered here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2869

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This would be a lot easier with SFTP, which is an extension to SSH that supports more complex file operations than SCP.  Virtually all modern Unix and Linux distributions support it.  To use it, just run this command to connect to the server:

```
sftp server
```

Then you can use the `ls` and `cd` commands to browse around and find the file you're looking for.  Once you've found it, use the `get` command to download it.  For instance, to download `file.txt` in your current working directory on the server to your current working directory on your local machine, just run:

```
get file.txt
```

To download `/home/pavpanchekha/textfiles/file.txt` on the server to `~/textfiles/` on your local machine, instead run:

```
get /home/pavpanchekha/textfiles/file.txt ~/textfiles/
```

Conversely, you can also upload files in this manner.  To upload `file.txt` from your local current working directory to the current working directory of the server, type:

```
put file.txt
```

You can also use full paths for each like you can with `get`:

```
put ~/textfiles/file.txt /home/pavpanchekha/textfiles/file.txt
```

For a full list of available SFTP commands, just run `help` at the `sftp>` prompt.

Comment: This is pretty cool, thanks.  Is there any way to launch one in reverse if I'm already in an SSH connection?  Otherwise I find myself ssh'ing somewhere, realizing that I want to transfer a file, quitting the SSH connection, making an SFTP connection, quitting that, and going back to SSH.

Comment: @pav: The `SSH_CLIENT` environment variable contains the IP address of the connecting host among other information.  You can use that to create a shell alias to easily SFTP back to the originating host.  Just add this line to `~/.bashrc` on the server: `alias sftpback="sftp $(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}')"`  Then disconnect and reconnect from SSH so the change takes effect, or run that as if it were a command so it takes effect immediately.  From there on, you can just run `sftpback` to SFTP back to the client you're connecting from, regardless of which one it is.

Comment: This is best!!! Thank you for saving me from NANO (editing file online) it makes the process so simple.

Answer (score 0):

The console file manager Midnight Commander (mc) has a VFS system that allows SFTP connection/file managing to remote servers. It also runs in [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) on Windows. The default interface shows two independent panels; we could open the SFTP remote directory in one of them and transfer files to/from the other panel easily. Includes a file editor/viewer (mcedit) with syntax highlighting.